# What is happening under the hood in javascript when using the Array brackets notation

Tags: javascript, arrays, operators

I have generally found javascript to be transparent, in that there are very few black boxes where "magic" just happens and you should just accept and look the other way, however I have not found any answer to how the Array brackets `[]` notation actually works under the hood.

```
let arr = [4, 5, 6, 7]
console.log(arr[3]) // <- How does this work?
```

What is javascript doing to access the item at index 3. Does it internally call some method on the Array.prototype?

With an object, the [] is a shortcut for a property accessor.

```
let obj = {
  a: 'hello',
  b: 'world'
}
obj['a'] === obj.a // true
```

Is an array then just an object with a long list of integer based properties?

```
let objArray = {
   0: 'hello',
   1: 'world'
}
let realArray = ['hello', 'world']

objArray[0] === 'hello' // true
realArray[0] === 'hello' // true

objArray.0 // SyntaxError: Unexpected number
realArray.0 // SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```

I have seen many many online discussions that all come to the conclusion that you cannot overload the brackets notation to truly subclass an Array but I have never seen an explanation on what magic is happening under the hood that allows the Array to work the way it does.

The obvious follow up question is whether there is any way to intercept the bracket notation access to define your own behavior, but I think I already know the answer to that.

Comment: `[ ]` is an operator.  I imagine if you could overload operators, you could customize what's happening under the hood.  I imagine `objArray.'0'` would work as the key is a string, but after trying, it does not.  Using it as the key *does* work, however: `objArray[0] === objArray['0']`

Comment: *"What is javascript doing to access the item at index 3."* Nothing; it is just accessing the index. Everything beyond that is part of the underlying JS Engine, and may be different depending on what data-structure this particular engine is using to store this particular array. Because even that (the underlying data structure for an array) may differ based on the current data in the Array and what changes this Array went through. What behaviour do you want to implement by overloading a property access?

Comment: @Thomas An example is creating a Linked List. In javascript I can created the list structure however I like, lets say for instance its an es6 class. I can then define a `Symbol.Iterator` in order to use my new list instance in a `for...of` loop or using the spread operator `...list` or in deconstruction `let [a, b, c] = list`. For all intents and purposes I have a nice new data type. The one thing I can't do is use brackets notation to access individual buckets. I would like the ability to do something similar to the `Symbol.Iterator` so I can define my own behavior for `list[0]` etc

Answer (score 2):

You'd probably have to look at the implementation code to know precisely what's going on, but the basic idea is that arrays are actually layered atop objects.

This is backwards:

> With an object, the [] is a shortcut for a property accessor.

The bracket notation is more fundamental.  Thus, `obj['foo']` and `obj.foo` work the same, but there is no equivalent for `obj['foo & bar']`, which is perfectly legitimate, and will respond with a value if `obj` has a key named `"foo & bar"`.

> Is an array then just an object with a long list of integer based properties?

Not quite, but you're not far off.  Arrays are objects with the `Array` prototype, and with a little bit of additional magic to set the `length` property when new keys are added, or remove keys when that `length` is set.

And no, you cannot override the `[]` operator for your own purposes.

Comment: *"Is an array then just an object with a long list of integer based properties?" -> "Not quite, but you're not far off."* afaik. in the worst case scenario, a sparse array with mixed types of content, an Array may be stored exactly as that, a dictionary with a long list of integer based properties.

Comment: well... it still needs to have access to the `Array.prototype` methods, and it has to be able to do the magic with `length`.  But the underlying structure could well be a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

> Is an array then just an object with a long list of integer based properties?

Yes, in it's simplest form, an Array is an Object with a list of integer base properties that is based on the Array prototype (which gives access to all the array methods like map, forEach, etc.)

As for intercepting the bracket notation, no, I have not seen anything that would allow that besides creating your own Object that has the methods you need (and then only access that object via the appropriate methods).

More info from MDN:

> Arrays are list-like objects whose prototype has methods to perform traversal and mutation operations. Neither the length of a JavaScript array nor the types of its elements are fixed. Since an array's length can change at any time, and data can be stored at non-contiguous locations in the array, JavaScript arrays are not guaranteed to be dense; this depends on how the programmer chooses to use them. In general, these are convenient characteristics; but if these features are not desirable for your particular use, you might consider using typed arrays.
>
> Arrays cannot use strings as element indexes (as in an associative array) but must use integers. Setting or accessing via non-integers using bracket notation (or dot notation) will not set or retrieve an element from the array list itself, but will set or access a variable associated with that array's object property collection. The array's object properties and list of array elements are separate, and the array's traversal and mutation operations cannot be applied to these named properties.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#Array_object

Comment: OOP: where everything is just an object at its core